# How to use the "Update Contact" function to insert new records into another DE?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, subscriber-key

I would like to know how a contact can be introduced inside a new Data Extension after completing a Journey, without the need of having the subscriber key already inside that new Data Extension, and without using Queries. I was told this could be done with the "Update Contact" activity, because even though it has the "update" term in it, it can also insert new records into another DE.

Comment: Did you try creating a new sendable data extensions and using it in Update Contact activity?

Comment: @LukasLunow thank you. We tried this and it worked. Now we would also like to know if there is a possibility of copying fields from DE that starts the Journey to the new DE.

Comment: It is not possible, no. You will need to use e.g. Ampscript to fetch the values from the original journey DE, or copy these fields manually. Keep in mind, that using Update Contact to "move" all the values is not optimal, as it is limited to (AFAIR) only 5-5 fields in one activity.

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000390236&type=1&language=en_US

Comment: Yes, and what @EazyE wrote...